# Rails giving error message as "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" when defining my own method and passing the parameters from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a method of my own name in a controller and which will accept the parameters from a form and will save to the database and also will say a message in another HTML page is that " The details you filled are" and then display the values. I have already read the tuitoral but i am facing this error when i try to do it with my own method. When I searched the error I have found out the similar error messages but couldn't resolve my issue. Please help as i was stuck with this one for entire day.

My Controller

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def respond
    @user=User.new(params(:user))
    @user.save
  end
end`
```

index.html.erb

```
<%=form_tag :action=>"respond" do%>
  <p><label>Enter Name</%label><%=text_field :user, @name%>
  </p>
  <p><label>Enter Age</%label><%=text_field :user, @age%>
  </p>
  <p><label>Enter color</%label><%=text_field :user, @color%>
  </p>
  <p><%=submit_tag "submit"%></p>
<%end%>`
```

respond.html.erb

```
<p>My Name is <%=@user.name%></p>
<p>My age is <%=@user.age%></p>
<p>My color is <%=@user.color%></p>
```

In routes.rb I have put the below line

```
D:\hellorail\bin>rake routes
```

(in D:/hellorail)
             Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
           respond_hello_index POST /hello/respond(.:format) hello#respond
           hello_index GET  /hello(.:format)         hello#index

rake routes output
D:\hellorail\bin>rake routes
(in D:/hellorail)

```
respond_hello_index POST /hello/respond(.:format) hello#respond
hello_index GET  /hello(.:format)         hello#index
```

Error message

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Extracted source (around line #3):

class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def respond
    @user=User.new(params(:user))
    @user.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm wildly guessing here, but this:

```
User.new(params(:user))
```

should probably be

```
User.new(params[:user])
```

The params method returns a hash(-like-object), and you access contents via square brackets.
The error is caused by the fact that params(:user) is actually calling the "params" method with the parameter ":user" - and this method does not accept any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
params[:user]
```

Not:

```
params(:user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using square brackets in the respond method for params hash like this:

```
@user=User.new(params[:user])
```